# How to find and replace string In many files

Tags: php, ubuntu

What I need Is to go thru a directory that contains subdirectories. In each second level directory has a third level directory that contains a file with same file name for every second level directory.

In each of those files made in PHP there Is a variable that contains like:  appversion = 'YYYYMMDD'. I need to modify this date for each appearance To eg appversion = '20190301'.

How to do this In Shell or with PHP?

Edit: sorry for the malformed question, this is what defines better what I need to do really

I am afraid the question was a little malformed. 
What I need to do is: 
1. To find in all subdirectories a file called "productver.php".
2.  In each "productver.php" file find a variable called 'appversion'.
3.  Replace the value with a given value that i provide. 
Example: I provide a date that is "20190324" and I want to change this to the value of all 'appversion' variables. E.g. 'appversion = 20180121'  ==> 'appversion = 20190324'. For this reason, I am afraid simple replace is not enough as I only need to replace the part which is on the right side of the "=" character. And I cannot seek for a specific date, because the dates of this variable change. All I know is that I need to replace those dates, on the right side of the "=" sign of variable 'appversion'.

Comment: is it a one time issue or you need an automation? This can be done using IDE (Search and Replace or Refactor..). Otherwise a shell script using sed would be perfect.

Comment: PHP `str_replace('YYYYMMDD', '20190301', $string)`, `sed` could be used in shell.

Comment: Did you look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files?

Comment: Please see my edit on the main question. Sorry for the mess...